# How calculate autosize for group buttons in Unity3D

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have button's horizontal layout group with TextMeshPro. How can I calculate auto sizing font for it and set minimum value on all buttons? It's need for relative UI.

I have now:

[image]

And how I want:
[image]

I tried this code:

```
public class FontSizeController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        SetMinFontForAnswers(transform,
            FindMinFontSizeAnswerOptions(transform));
    }

    private void SetMinFontForAnswers(Transform answerPanel, float minFontSize)
    {
        for (var answerIndex = 0; answerIndex < answerPanel.childCount; answerIndex++)
        {
            var meshProUgui = answerPanel.GetChild(answerIndex).GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            meshProUgui.fontSize = minFontSize;
        }
    }

    private float FindMinFontSizeAnswerOptions(Transform answerOptions)
    {
        var minFontSize = -1f;

        for (var answerIndex = 0; answerIndex < answerOptions.childCount; answerIndex++)
        {
            var component = answerOptions.GetChild(answerIndex).GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            component.enableAutoSizing = true;
            component.ForceMeshUpdate();
            if (IsAnswerOptionActive(answerOptions, answerIndex) && IsMinFontSizeOrNotInitialized(component, minFontSize))
            {
                minFontSize = component.fontSize;
            }

            component.enableAutoSizing = false;
        }

        return minFontSize;
    }

    private bool IsAnswerOptionActive(Transform answerOptions, int answerIndex)
    {
        return answerOptions.GetChild(answerIndex).gameObject.activeSelf;
    }
    private bool IsMinFontSizeOrNotInitialized(TMP_Text textComponent, float minFontSize)
    {
        return textComponent.fontSize < minFontSize || minFontSize == -1f;
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work on Start and work only in Update method. But when I used it in Update method I can see when text font size changing. It is quickly but I want do this before panel will be render.

Question panel is not active by default

[image]

AnswerOptionsPanel:

[image]

TextMeshPro Text in AnswerOptionsPanel:

[image]

Comment: Your request is confusing. Are you asking how to remove the auto-sizing of the text?

Comment: No, I want to use auto-size for finding optimal font size for all buttons and set on all of buttons min found value of font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your Text assets current size with using this method;

```
Text.cachedTextGenerator.fontSizeUsedForBestFit
```

You can compare your texts instant size and then change.
For example;

```js
UnityEngine.UI.Text[] myTexts;

void OptimiseTextSizes()
{

    int minSize = 999;
    foreach (UnityEngine.UI.Text t in myTexts)
    {
        if (t.cachedTextGenerator.fontSizeUsedForBestFit < minSize)
        {
            minSize = t.cachedTextGenerator.fontSizeUsedForBestFit;
        }
    }

    foreach (UnityEngine.UI.Text t in myTexts)
    {
        t.resizeTextMaxSize = minSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I use it with TextMeshPro?

Comment: Yes, you can use.

Comment: You can see the optimised size in TextMeshPro with like this;

`text.fontSize`